# Do buffs affect your party or only the character you're using?

Tags: genshin-impact

I just want to know: if a character who ate the buff dies, do I have to feed the next character in the party the same buffs?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about party wide buff you get from foods like reduced stamina consumption, increased element damage / resistance and so on those are considered party buff not specific to a character. You can easily test: use a potion and then jump off a cliff. The buff icon should still be there after you are switched to the next character.

Answer (score 0):

No! The buff remains until the time runs out. And it applies to all the characters in a party.